Installing CH34xVCPDriver on mac
I've tried to install CH34xVCPDriver on my Mac M3 Sonoma and it's not working no matter what I do. I get an error message that says:
Install Tips error: The operation couldn't be completed.
(OSSystemExtensionErrorDomain error 10.)


what's not working? ... the installation process? ... the driver after installation?

The error you encountered (OSSystemExtensionErrorDomain error 10) typically means there is an issue with macOS blocking the installation of third-party system extensions. This can happen when the driver is not properly signed, or macOS's security features like SIP (System Integrity Protection) are preventing the installation.
If you haven't tried and you are sure that the OS version supports the driver, go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy and in the General tab, look for a message stating that the system software from the developer was blocked. Click on Allow and try the installation again.
